# Row equivalent between two invertible matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Kind of a stupid question, but I couldn't find any large statement to cover it up for me.

---

> If $A$ and $B$ are invertible matrices, are $A$ and $B$ row equivalent?

---

**Answer**: In my opinion yes , if they are invertible , we can reduce them to the identity matrix , so both matrices have the same row echelon form.

am I right ? or they are not equivalent because from A we can get to Identity matrix but not to B.

Comment: Two matrices $A$ and $B$ are row equivalent if you can find an invertible matrix $C$ such that $A=CB$. In the given case they are row-equivalent because $A=\underbrace{(AB^{-1})}_{C}\,B$. This also shows that since both $A$ and $B$ are row equivalent to $I$ so we can go from $B$ to $A$ via row operations.

Comment: May I ask how did you find C in this case scenario? You did the equation A*$A^-1$ = B*$B^-1$ ?

Answer (score 2):

$A$ and $B$ are invertible, so they are row equivalent to the identity matrix.
$A$ and $B$ are row equivalent to the same matrix, so $A$ and $B$ are row equivalent.